# How to omit start/stop character in Code 39 barcode interpretation line?

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, code39

Is there a way to omit the start/stop character in the interpretation line of a Code 39 barcode? Obviously the barcode itself should contain them.

```
        ||| |||| || | ||||
           *1234567890*       <-- How to remove * here?
```

Here's the ZPL string I am using:

```
^XA
^FO100,200^BY3
^B3N,N,100,Y,N
^FD1234567890^FS
^XZ
```

You can view the ZPL above in an online ZPL viewer [here](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFO100%2C200%5EBY3%0A%5EB3N%2CN%2C100%2CY%2CN%0A%5EFD1234567890%5EFS%0A%5EXZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Simple way to do this would be to disable the printing of interpretation line

then add in a ^A font line with your data to print your text

```
^XA
^FO100,200^BY3
^B3N,N,100,N,N
^FD1234567890^FS
^FT250,325
^ADN,18,20^FD1234567890^FS**
^XZ
```

Sample can be found here [Label](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFO100%2C200%5EBY3%0A%5EB3N%2CN%2C100%2CN%2CN%0A%5EFD1234567890%5EFS%0A%5EFT250%2C325%0A%5EADN%2C18%2C20%5EFD1234567890%5EFS%0A%5EXZ)

Comment: Can you provide an example? I added the following: `^AAN,10,10` and it just shows a barcode, no text. See the link supplied in the question above.

Comment: ^XA

^FO100,200^BY3

^B3N,N,100,N,N

^FD1234567890^FS

^FT250,325

^ADN,18,20^FD1234567890^FS

^XZ

You need the ^FT command to locate the Text Field

[link](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFO100%2C200%5EBY3%0A%5EB3N%2CN%2C100%2CN%2CN%0A%5EFD1234567890%5EFS%0A%5EFT250%2C325%0A%5EADN%2C18%2C20%5EFD1234567890%5EFS%0A%5EXZ "Link to Label")